# SQL SUM() Function error

Tags: mysql, sum

I am trying to count the SUM of a column.

```
SELECT SUM(Player Count) as NoOfPlayers 
FROM members
```

I get an error in the "Count" word as this is a key word in SQL

Any way of getting around this? I cannot change the name of the table column as it will be a monthly feed.

Comment: @AlexK. still getting the error

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: then show us your db schema,

Comment: You can't have a column with a space character in it.  We need to see the table description.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a field with spaces you need include back ticks `

```
SELECT SUM(`Player Count`) as NoOfPlayers 
FROM members
```

Comment: @AaronC In which case the error lies somewhere else.

Comment: Make sure you are useing "ticks" not Singe Quotes.  It's found on the (Shift + ~)

Comment: @SariRahal yes i used the correct ones, the error has gone away from count but now is highlighted under the player word

Comment: @AaronC Then you are using the wrong field name, show us your create table statement

Comment: Are you sure this column exists?  Show your table schema then.

Comment: Can you show the "Create Table"?  Run this "Show Create Table [MySQL Schema].member" replace [MySQL Schema] with the schema name.

Comment: As a workaround i counted another column with same values but different column name. Thanks for the help - needed a quickfix

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes, it will underline the field since it's an invalid column name, but it works